# I m not able to use the enter key while using whatsApp..?

Tags: whatsapp

I am not able to use the enter key, if I use that the msg gets sent on whatsApp. How do I hit enter and start a new sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its an option in WhatsApp settings which lets you send msgs when you hit Enter button in keyboard.

1. Hit three dots in bottom right corner of screen in whatsapp.
2. In the menu select **Settings**.
3. Choose **Chats and Calls** in the settings options.
4. **Turn** **Off** *Enter Sends a message*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work for everybody: With the option of sending through the use of the return button **turned off** Whatsapp still sends messages when I hit return, be it in the browser version of Opera or in the desktop version of Whatsapp. It just doesn't react to this setting at all. Since this issue really spoils all the fun with Whatsapp I switched to Telegram: Good riddance!